# Can't load from csv, bin

Tags: python, csv

I need to implement a method of saving data in txt, csv, bin and unloading them. I select files using the `select_file` method, which checks which file format I have selected and calls the corresponding function.

```py
data = {
    "name": heater.name,
    "kW": heater.kW,
    "sections": heater.sections,
    "thermostat": heater.thermostat,
    "cordLength": heater.cordLength,
    "maxFanSpeed": heater.maxFanSpeed,
    "isWaterFan": heater.isWaterFan,     
    "country": heater.country,
    "manufacturer": heater.manufacturer,
    "dm": heater.dm,
    "state": heater.state,
}
```

CSV:

```py
def save_csv_file(self, data):  # Сэйв csv
    filename = "heaters/" + f"heater{data['name'].upper()}.csv"
    with open(filename, "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(
            [
                "Назва: ",
                "Потужність: ",
                "Секції: ",
                "Термостат: ",
                "Довжина шнуру: ",
                "Максимальна кількість обертів: ",
                "Це водний тепловетилятор: ",
                "Країна-постачальник: ",
                "Фірма-виробник: ",
                "Діаметр: ",
                "Стан: ",
            ]
        )
        writer.writerow(
            [
                data["name"],
                data["kW"],
                data["sections"],
                "Наявний" if data["thermostat"] else "Відсутній",
                data["cordLength"],
                data["maxFanSpeed"],
                "Так" if data["isWaterFan"] else "Ні",
                data["country"],
                data["manufacturer"],
                data["dm"],
                data["state"],
            ]
        )

def load_csv_file(self, filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r", newline="") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            header = next(reader)  # Skip the header row

            
            expected_columns = [
                "Назва: ",
                "Потужність: ",
                "Секції: ",
                "Термостат: ",
                "Довжина шнуру: ",
                "Максимальна кількість обертів: ",
                "Це водний тепловетилятор: ",
                "Країна-постачальник: ",
                "Фірма-виробник: ",
                "Діаметр: ",
                "Стан: ",
            ]
            if header != expected_columns:
                raise ValueError("Invalid CSV file format")

            # Read the row containing the data
            data_row = next(reader)

            # Extract the values from the data row
            data = {
                "name": data_row[0],
                "kW": data_row[1],
                "sections": data_row[2],
                "thermostat": True if data_row[3] == "Наявний" else False,
                "cordLength": data_row[4],
                "maxFanSpeed": data_row[5],
                "isWaterFan": True if data_row[6] == "Так" else False,
                "country": data_row[7],
                "manufacturer": data_row[8],
                "dm": data_row[9],
                "state": data_row[10],
            }

            # Update the selected_heater attribute
            self.selected_heater = FanHeater(
                data["dm"],
                data["manufacturer"],
                data["country"],
                data["maxFanSpeed"],
                data["isWaterFan"],
                data["name"],
                data["kW"],
                data["sections"],
                data["thermostat"],
                data["cordLength"],
                data["state"],
            )

            # Display the heater details
            HeaterGui.show_heater_details()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found.")
```

BIN:

```py
def save_binary_file(self, data):
    filename = "heaters/" + f"heater{data['name'].upper()}.bin"
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(data, file)
def load_binary_file(self, filename):  # Загрузка bin
    with open(filename, "rb") as file:
        data = pickle.load(file)
    return data
```

Select file by this function:

```py
def select_file(self):
    filetypes = (
        ("Текстовый файл", "*.txt"),
        ("CSV файл", "*.csv"),
        ("Бинарный файл", "*.bin"),
    )
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes)

    if filename:
        try:
            heater = None
            try:
                heater = FanHeater()
                heater.load_text_file(filename)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                try:
                    heater = FanHeater()
                    heater.load_csv_file(filename)
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    try:
                        heater = FanHeater()
                        heater.load_binary_file(filename)
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        messagebox.showerror("Error", "File not found")

            if heater:
                self.selected_heater = heater
                self.show_heater_details()

        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No file selected")
```

I tried double-checking the data in the files, the order of the variables, and so on. Nothing worked. Error: "list index out of range" remains.

I assume the error occurs on these lines:

```
if filename:
    try:
        heater = None
        try:
            heater = FanHeater()
            heater.load_text_file(filename)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            try:
                heater = FanHeater()
                heater.load_csv_file(filename)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                try:
                    heater = FanHeater()
                    heater.load_binary_file(filename)
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "File not found")

        if heater:
            self.selected_heater = heater
            self.show_heater_details()

    except Exception as e: # Attention
        messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))
```

The most interesting thing is that the `load_csv_file` function itself doesn't call because it leaves try (print doesn't output anything). Although it is logical that the error is caused by incorrect handling of `load_csv_file`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "C:\Users\zurto\Desktop\ONPU\Python\lr5.py", line 785, in select_file heater.load_text_file(filename) 
 File "C:\Users\zurto\Desktop\ONPU\Python\lr5.py", line 98, in load_text_file self.cordLength = lines[4].strip()

Line 98:
                self.cordLength = lines[4].strip()
```

Comment: What line does that error occur on?

Comment: please share the full error [edit] and add it

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make myself clear. The error is not in the compilation. It's called by the select_file function @azro

Comment: Please give us a specific line to focus on.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know where to pay attention myself. I've redone everything so many times, I have no idea what could be wrong. The program gives me the impression that I'm accessing an index outside the list, although I'm not doing that. @tadman

Comment: there is no "compilation" in python, just runtime. Again : please [edit] and share the full stacktrace (the lines ending by the error you mention), the errors tells WHICH line fail we need to know to help you, without it we can't do anything

Comment: @arzo, in "select_file" 
except Exception as e:
                print(e)
just print "list index out of range". This is all the information I have. The program actually works, but gives incorrect results

Comment: I edited, hope I was able to clarify. It's just hard for me to find the error myself, but it's there.

Comment: Add the line `raise` above `messagebox.showerror` to make the stack trace visible. Also see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Ty, @mkrieger1 .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zurto\Desktop\ONPU\Python\lr5.py", line 785, in select_file
    heater.load_text_file(filename)
  File "C:\Users\zurto\Desktop\ONPU\Python\lr5.py", line 98, in load_text_file
    self.cordLength = lines[4].strip()

Now i can understand what problem is. The most likely culprit is the select_file function

Comment: It can help to put that in the question as an edit, the formatting's easier, but that's a much stronger hint as to where the problem is. Which line is line 98?

Comment: Most likely the program opens a CSV file and tries to read it as a txt file. I'm fixing it now.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the function `select_file`. Because the file was found, but its format was not correct, the program tried to read txt to csv, that's why there were problems with list index out of range. The corrected function looks like this:

```
 if filename:
            try:
                heater = None
                if (filename[-3:] == "txt"):
                    heater = FanHeater()
                    heater.load_text_file(filename)
                if (filename[-3:] == "csv"):
                    heater = FanHeater()
                    heater.load_csv_file(filename)
                if (filename[-3:] == "bin"):
                    heater = FanHeater()
                    heater.load_binary_file(filename)
                    
                if heater:
                    self.selected_heater = heater
                    self.show_heater_details()
            except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))
```